# How to make a directions application when others click on the point they want to go to

Tags: java, android

I want when the user selects a location on google map, creates a maker and displays a popup asking if the user wants directions from the current location to the selected location, if OK draws the line

Any suggestion would be helpful to me
Thanks

Comment: You should google it you can get lot of examples to create directions

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google Direction API for this. You can refer the [official documentation from Google Direction API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro)

And also you can [refer this example for Google map direction](https://www.wingsquare.com/blog/drawing-driving-route-directions-between-two-locations-using-google-directions-in-google-map-android/).

[image]